# Get object from Local Storage Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular8

I have a localstorage which is storing some data. I am trying to get the data in a component using `localStorage.getItem('id');` but it is undefined. The problem is, `localStorage` is storing `id` in a strange format. It is stored like `abcabcabc.id` Now there are multiple such parameters in localStorage and for each logged in user the string `abcabcabc` changes. How can I still get `id` value. Can I compare string or something to get values? Like if it contains string `.id` only read that value? If yes, can you explain how would that be achieved?

localstorage:

```
abcabcabc.username.id = sdfsdfsdfs
abcabcabc.username.refreshToken = sdfsdfs
abcabcabc.username.accessToken = ertsdffdg
```

Comment: Save your id without other Params. `localStorage.setItem('YourIdVaribale')`;

Comment: the problem is, I am using AWS Cognito and it sends it in a particular format only... like: ```abcabcabc.username.id, abcabcabc.username.name``` etc. And there is no way to only get ```id```. How can I acheive that in typescript code?

Comment: I am looking for something like ```if string.includes(id) return```  it

Comment: is there no way for you to get the username in the component? (maybe using a service which stores the data for the current user?) that way, you can access {username}.id

Comment: You can do exactly that `string.includes(id)` `return string.substring(0,9)`. 0 & 9 are for abcabcabc

Comment: but my problem is how to use it ```.include(id)``` in the following statement: ```localStorage.getItem(string.include(id)); return string.substring(0,9);``` I know this is incorrect. Can you show me how can I achieve it in typescript?

Comment: unfortunately it did not help @NicholasK my case is a little different than this

Comment: Sth like `while(string.includes(id)){ var x = string.substring(0,9); return x;`

Comment: @Ferdinand can you tell me how will I use it in localStorage get item? I am very new to angular not sure

Comment: I need to see how you set the data first.

Comment: I have added sample localStorage object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not know the exact key stored in localStorage fetch all of them and then iterate over it. Next, match part of the key that you know i.e *id* as illustrated below:

```
// fetch all key-value pairs from local storage
const localStorageKeys = { ...localStorage };

// iterate over them
for (const index in localStorageKeys) {

  // see if key contains id
  if (index.includes('id')) {

    // fetch value for corresponding key 
    console.log(localStorageKeys[index]);

  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect @Nicholas K. Thank you

Comment: Can you also look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889510/angular-8-logout-user-on-aws-cognito-token-expire/64889907#64889907 it has been posted by a friend of mine. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, that question is way too broad. If it can be edited to narrow down to a *specific* problem I would be glad to have a crack at it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again. For 2nd question I have added some code above with a comment. I am trying to get expiry time in ```tokenExpiration``` and check it with local time to see if it is greater log the user out. Will ```httpinterceptor``` be able to check it automatically when condition becomes valid or I need a manual trigger? Can you explain how it would work? Thanks.

Comment: intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       this.token =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokenExpiration'));
        if (this.tokenExpired(this.token)) {
             Auth.signOut().then((res) => {
                this.authState === 'signedout';
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
              });
        } else {
            return
          }
      }
      private tokenExpired(token: number) {
        const expiry = token;
        return (Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000)) >= expiry;
      }

Comment: Please do not edit any questions/answers in this post as it deals with another topic. If you have another question ask it separately. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nicholas K , I have asked my friend to ask this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897407/logout-user-and-redirect-user-to-login-on-token-expiration-angular-8

Answer (score 0):

localStorage sets data as a map of key-value pairs, so :

```
var id = {key:"id", value:"sdfsdfsdfs"}
//JSON.stringify converts the JavaScript object id into a string 
localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(id));
```

now you get the data by:

```
var getTheId = localStorage.getItem('id');
//you can use JSON.parse() if you need to print it
console.log('getTheId: ', JSON.parse(getTheId));
```

This is how you would normally do it, but since I don't know how you had set the data, you would instead get the data by:

```
var x = localStorage.getItem(id);//normally getting your id
//parse it
var st = JSON.parse(x);
var ids = [];
while(st.includes(id)){
//this is to only get the abcabacabc
var newId = st.substring(0,9);
ids.push(newId);
}
console.log(ids);
```