# Logout User and Redirect User to Login on Token Expiration - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-http-interceptors

I receive `idToken` and I am also getting the expiration time `expTime` in timestamp format eg: `1605803717` which basically expires in 1 day. I want to log the user out and redirect the user to login page if `idToken` expires. I have implemented a HTTPInterceptor as below:

```
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  this.token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getToken"));
  if (this.tokenExpired(this.token)) {
    Auth.signOut().then((res) => {
      this.authState === "signedout";
      this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

private tokenExpired(token: number) {
  const expiry = token;
  return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) >= expiry;
}
```

My question is to know if this implementation will work automatically I mean, will this interceptor automatically be triggered when `idToken` expires or do I need to setup some kind of trigger? How does HTTPInterceptors work? Will it be able to catch time expiration and logout user or I have to implement something else to catch `idToken` expiration?

Comment: you should return observable here, https://angular.io/guide/http#write-an-interceptor

Comment: you can make some console log messages, to check your implementation or you can make the token expiration to few seconds to check if the logout and the redirection is done or not !

Answer (score 0):

One way i have implemented it is to catch the Unauthorized error with code 401.
And handle the error by in our case was to update the token using refreshToken but ofc you can logout and redirect if you wish so

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        // Unauthorized
        if (err && err.status === 401) {
          // Logout User
          // Redirect
          // etc.
        } else {
          // This will forward other errors since 
          // this interceptor code is invoked on every http request
          return next.handle(req);
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```